# How do I determine which GStreamer plugin decodebin3 selected?

Tags: c++, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I need to determine which decoder plugin `decodebin3` has selected.

I've found that I can't always link it to certain downstream elements after it spawns the source pad.  But if I "disable" (change the rank) of a given unusable plugin, I can make my pipeline linkable/functional.  I want to dynamically switch the selection, in the event the downstream elements can't link.

The older `decodebin` had signals like `autoplug-select`, which looks to have been a means for figuring out the plugins in play.  But `decodebin3` doesn't have equivalent signals?

When I have debug logging enabled, I have seen the name of the child plugin (which is how can manually disable a "bad" one in POC manner to test my concept).  Is there a way to iterate through the children inside a `decodebin3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself.  Basically, the element created by this plugin is a "bin" (which is why it's called `decodeBIN3`!), and therefore one can use `gst_bin_iterate_elements` to iterate through the child elements within it.  Then, it's possible to get the factory an element was produced by, and from there check the type of factory e.g. being a decoder.  You can can also get the unique id of the "factory type".

Here are the major functions to use when formulating your own solution for a similar issue. (Sorry it would be a pain, and perhaps confusing, if I posted all the code for my exact use case...)

```
gst_bin_iterate_elements( GST_BIN( decoder ) );

GstElement *element( GST_ELEMENT_CAST( g_value_peek_pointer( &value ) ) );

GstElementFactory *factory( gst_element_get_factory( element ) );

const gboolean isDecoder( gst_element_factory_list_is_type( factory, GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY_TYPE_DECODER ) );

const GType factoryType( gst_element_factory_get_element_type( factory ) );
```

Comment: Do you know how to force `decodebin` to use a specific element? In my case, I need to add the `rtponvifparse` element to the pipeline. I thought that using signals like `autoplug-factories` might be a solution, but I can't find the solution.

Comment: Yeah, I'd be happy to help with that.  Please create a question and share the link to it here.  I'll post some code.

Comment: Thank you! Here is the question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73963947/forcing-the-use-of-the-rtponvifparse-element-in-uridecodebin