# Forcing the use of the rtponvifparse element in uridecodebin

Tags: c, gstreamer, rtp, gstreamer-1.0

In the gstreamer pipeline I use `uridecodebin` element to auto-select suitable elements to parse and decode RTSP stream. Now I need to add a `rtponvifparse` element to this pipeline. The `rtponvifparse` element has ***application/x-rtp*** caps, so it should be placed between the elements generated by the `uridecodebin` element.

Is there any way to tell the `uridecodebin` element to use the `rtponvifparse` element?

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar with decodebin3.  I didn't see a means to *directly* set what the selection would be.  I guess that's viewed as a sort of "anti-pattern" since the point of these dynamic selectors is to figure this out for us.  I did, however, arrive an *indirect* means to achieve this.

The dynamic selection works by finding those options which are possible.  Then, the "best one" is chosen by its designated "rank".  When two plugins have the same rank, I'm not certain on what the tie breaker is.  I believe that is covered in GStreamer docs though, if you need to figure it out. It might luck, or might be something arbitrary like alphabetical name order?  Anyway, the point is that you will want to manual manage the ranks.

Here's a way to spit out ALL the available decoders and their present rank onto the console.

```
const auto decoders( gst_element_factory_list_get_elements(
    GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY_TYPE_DECODER, GST_RANK_NONE ) );
qDebug() << "GStreamer Decoders: ";
for( GList *it = decoders; it != NULL; it = it->next )
{        
    GType factoryType( gst_element_factory_get_element_type(
        GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY_CAST( it->data ) ) );
    GstElement *decoder( GST_ELEMENT_CAST( it->data ) );
    const auto name( gst_element_get_name( decoder ) );        
    qDebug() << name << factoryType << " - " << pluginRank( name );
}
gst_plugin_feature_list_free( decoders );
```

Sorry, I used Qt and only somewhat tweaked this post for "general use", but it should be easy to employ `cout` or whatever logger you might want instead.  In theory, `gst_element_factory_list_get_elements` could filter the list even more - e.g. ONLY video decoders etc. though I ran into odd compilation issues trying to get that to work.  The second parameter I'm passing there `GST_RANK_NONE` specs to fetch any plugins regardless of rank, but you can change that to for more precision.

Note that the most important function there is, of course, `pluginRank`.

Ok, now that you can iterate over all the options, and see all the critical data, here's the most important part. You can use these functions I wrote (or some spin off) to manipulate the ranks.

```
gboolean setPluginRank( const gchar *factoryName, const guint rank )
{
    auto plugin( pluginFeature( factoryName ) );
    if( !plugin ) return FALSE;
    gst_plugin_feature_set_rank( plugin, rank );
    gst_object_unref( plugin );
    return TRUE;
}

// returns initial rank, setting up for later rank restoration
guint disablePluginAutoSelect( const gchar *factoryName )
{
    auto plugin( pluginFeature( factoryName ) );
    if( !plugin ) return GST_RANK_NONE;
    const guint rank( gst_plugin_feature_get_rank( plugin ) );
    gst_plugin_feature_set_rank( plugin, GST_RANK_NONE );
    gst_object_unref( plugin );
    return rank;
}
```

Here's the direct GStreamer source / comments on the ranking enums and how you aren't literally bound to the constants.

```
/**
 * GstRank:
 * @GST_RANK_NONE: will be chosen last or not at all
 * @GST_RANK_MARGINAL: unlikely to be chosen
 * @GST_RANK_SECONDARY: likely to be chosen
 * @GST_RANK_PRIMARY: will be chosen first
 *
 * Element priority ranks. Defines the order in which the autoplugger (or
 * similar rank-picking mechanisms, such as e.g. gst_element_make_from_uri())
 * will choose this element over an alternative one with the same function.
 *
 * These constants serve as a rough guidance for defining the rank of a
 * #GstPluginFeature. Any value is valid, including values bigger than
 * @GST_RANK_PRIMARY.
 */
typedef enum {
  GST_RANK_NONE                 = 0,
  GST_RANK_MARGINAL             = 64,
  GST_RANK_SECONDARY            = 128,
  GST_RANK_PRIMARY              = 256
} GstRank;
```

What you might be able to do in your case is simply set the target plugin to some huge rank number (like a max int value).

Otherwise, may want to save the initial ranks (in a hash perhaps), fiddle with them to setup what the auto plugin will do, and then restore them after that auto selection has been made.

Comment: Thank you. So if I understand correctly, it should be enough to set high RANK for the `rtponvifparse` element. I use the following code: `GstPluginFeature *plugin_feature = gst_registry_find_feature(gst_registry_get(), "rtponvifparse", GST_TYPE_ELEMENT_FACTORY);` to get the feature and then `gst_plugin_feature_set_rank(plugin_feature, GST_RANK_PRIMARY);` to set the RANK. Both are set before the pipeline is played. However, there is still no `rtponvifparse` element in the pipeline. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, what I posted here was what I thought was a direct answer to your question regarding https://stackoverflow.com/a/73820786/3220983.  But I failed to read your actual post here before going off on a tangent.  That was my mistake.  As I understand it, what you really want is to modify the internal structure of this bin, rather than simply set up a piece of it to be dynamically selected per it's intended design (as I described above).  Hope is not lost though!  I think it's likely possible to do as you are wishing...

Comment: I suggest that you iterate through the elements in the bin using the functions I listed in the other post.  Then, when you find the ones you need to inject a middle man between, unlink them, and then add your missing piece between them the way you would build pipeline from scratch.

Comment: Prior to this bin in the pipeline, add a `valve`. Then, "play" the bin to get the "natural" pieces in there. After that, open the valve so nothing else flows through for the moment (closing it later).  Then, you can perform the surgery on the innards.  If that won't work by itself, you might need to use an "idle probe" as well and/or pause the bin first.

Comment: Let me know if you need details on any of the above concepts. These dynamic elements can be very tricky to deal with.